# Excel VBA to loop data into email body

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I am trying to create a loop within VBA to have multiple selections from userform1's listbox2 when I hit the command button to draft an email with each selection in the following format. However, I can't figure out how to get more than just one selection into the body of the email. I tried to separate it into a "midbody" and add the code again, but it just adds the same entry twice. How can I make this loop work?

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()

    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object
    Dim midBody As String
    Dim wksheet As String
    Dim i As Integer



    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    For i = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1

        If ListBox2.Selected(i) = True Then
            wksheet = ListBox2.List(i)
            Sheets(wksheet).Activate

        End If


        If wksheet = "" Then
            MsgBox "Nothing is Selected"


           objMail.To = "myemail@me.com"

           'objMail.CC =

           objMail.Subject = ""


           Else

           midBody = activesheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                        activesheet.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & " through " & activesheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & " phase" & vbNewLine & _
                        "Phase ECD: " & activesheet.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                        "Baseline Finish: " & activesheet.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                        "Previous Finish: " & activesheet.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                        "Current Finish: " & activesheet.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                        "Weekly Schedule Variance: " & activesheet.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                        "CUM VAR to Baseline: " & activesheet.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                        "Slip Reason: " & vbNewLine & _
                        "Critical Path: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

           objMail.body = midBody & Sheets.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                        Sheets.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & " through " & Sheets.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & " phase" & vbNewLine & _
                        "Phase ECD: " & Sheets.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                        "Baseline Finish: " & Sheets.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                        "Previous Finish: " & Sheets.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                        "Current Finish: " & Sheets.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                        "Weekly Schedule Variance: " & Sheets.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                        "CUM VAR to Baseline: " & Sheets.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                        "Slip Reason: " & vbNewLine & _
                        "Critical Path: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

        End If
        i = i + 1

    Next i


        objMail.Save

        'Close the object
        Set objMail = Nothing

    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: @J Lawrence This syntax `objMail.body = midBody & Sheets.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value` seems to be wrong. `Sheets` Should have a reference like ` `objMail.body = midBody & Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value`. This change is to be made wherever `Sheets.Range` is appearing. Also please review whether `Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)` should be within ``IF Block`

Comment: @J Lawrence `Sheets("Sheet1")` Change `Sheet1` as per your working sheet,

Comment: @J Lawrence I have posted my answer a couple of hours ago. Still I am not quite sure that ` Exit For` in List Box Loop will allow loop to execute properly. If it gives problem and you are getting only single selected mail then change looping approach based on this SO post.<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40996274/emailing-listbox-content-multiple-entries>

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your code .Shifted `Next` of `For` towards later part of the code to include processing of loop. Removed redundant `midBody`.
Try This:

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Agent As String
    Dim EmailID As String
    Dim wksheet As String
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object


    With Me.ListBox2
    For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
        If .Selected(i) Then
            wksheet = .List(i)
            Exit For
        End If

    End With
     If wksheet = "" Then
        MsgBox "Nothing is Selected", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
     End If
    'r = Application.Match(wksheet, mySheet.Columns(1), 0)'choose one as per your data structure
    r = Application.Match(Agent, mySheet.Columns(1), 0)   'choose one as per your data structure


    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    'EmailID = mySheet.Range("D" & r).Value 'Uncomment it if this is required

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    With objMail
        .To = "myemail@me.com"    ' Or  EmailID
      ' .CC =
        .subject = ""

        .Body = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 ActiveSheet.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & " through " & ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & " phase" & vbNewLine & _
                 "Phase ECD: " & ActiveSheet.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "Baseline Finish: " & ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "Previous Finish: " & ActiveSheet.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "Current Finish: " & ActiveSheet.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "Weekly Schedule Variance: " & ActiveSheet.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "CUM VAR to Baseline: " & ActiveSheet.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "Slip Reason: " & vbNewLine & _
                 "Critical Path: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

       '.Display
       '.Send
        .Save
    End With
    Next i
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation

  End Sub
```

**EDIT**: Another version of code which works at my end. I have not created a `listbox` but simulated its working. This program loops correctly and send emails multiple times. Please remove `k` variable as per your `listbox` code . It is only for checking correct looping of the ptogram. Earlier version of program can be adjusted to your requirements if you provide sample data as what is the structure of `listbox`, from where it is picking emailid of the recipient, sample data of your worksheet etc.

```
Private Sub Command3_Click()
Dim subject As String, Body As String
Dim OutApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim k As Integer

  On Error Resume Next
   Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
  Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  If OutApp Is Nothing Then
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
  k = 4 ' remove it only for checking correct loop
  For intCurrentRow = 0 To k - 1  'List2.ListCount change k to List2.ListCount
     Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

     With OutMail
        ' List2.Selected(intCurrentRow) = True ' This is to be commented out after trials for looping

        .To = "abc@gmail.com"
        .subject = "Test 2nd time Email"
        .Body = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 ActiveSheet.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & " through " & ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & " phase" & vbNewLine & _
                 "Phase ECD: " & ActiveSheet.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "Baseline Finish: " & ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "Previous Finish: " & ActiveSheet.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "Current Finish: " & ActiveSheet.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "Weekly Schedule Variance: " & ActiveSheet.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "CUM VAR to Baseline: " & ActiveSheet.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "Slip Reason: " & vbNewLine & _
                 "Critical Path: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

        .Send
     End With
  Next intCurrentRow

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Outlook snapshot shows it is looping properly which was your main problem.
[image: outlookemails-snapshot]
***EDIT2:*** Earlier version of program simulated at my end on sample basis is running correctly and sending multiple mails. I do not have idea of your data setup so simulated for looping which was your main problem. Please try the program as it is , retain a copy and then make suitable adjustments for your data specific situation.
[image: orignal_rerun]

```
    Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim Agent As String
    Dim EmailID As String
    Dim wksheet As String
    Dim objOutlook As Object
    Dim objMail As Object


   ' With Me.ListBox2
    For i = 1 To 3
    'For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
     '   If .Selected(i) Then
      '      wksheet = .List(i)
       '     Exit For
       ' End If

    'End With
     If wksheet = "hello" Then
        MsgBox "Nothing is Selected", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
     End If
    'r = Application.Match(wksheet, mySheet.Columns(1), 0)'choose one as per your data structure
   ' r = Application.Match(Agent, mySheet.Columns(1), 0)   'choose one as per your data structure


    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    'EmailID = mySheet.Range("D" & r).Value 'Uncomment it if this is required

    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)

    With objMail
        .To = "abc@gmail.com"    ' Or  EmailID
      ' .CC =
        .subject = "original test"

        .Body = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 ActiveSheet.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & " through " & ActiveSheet.Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & " phase" & vbNewLine & _
                 "Phase ECD: " & ActiveSheet.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "Baseline Finish: " & ActiveSheet.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "Previous Finish: " & ActiveSheet.Range("H" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "Current Finish: " & ActiveSheet.Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "Weekly Schedule Variance: " & ActiveSheet.Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "CUM VAR to Baseline: " & ActiveSheet.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value & vbNewLine & _
                 "Slip Reason: " & vbNewLine & _
                 "Critical Path: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine

       '.Display
       .Send
        '.Save
    End With
    Next i
    Set objMail = Nothing
    Set objOutlook = Nothing

    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation

  End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the code...I can't get it to work. I am getting multiple errors. "end with" without a "with" on the first loop. Then if I remove them the code will run and I will get the MsgBox "done"; however no email is sent.

Comment: @J Lawrence I suggested this code only after testing on simulated conditions.May be while adjusting code to your situation, it may have been messed up.  I suggest you upload your sample file with your list box controls to any reputed site. I shall try to debug and give you a working file.

Comment: @JLawrence please see my edit and pay attention to comments in the code.

Comment: @JLawrence Please see my Edit2, regarding original version of the program.

Comment: ...not sure where I am having the problem integrating the code. I have been able to tweak it enough to run, but it is still not sending the email. What site are you referring to for upload of sample file?

Comment: @JLawrence Its mid-night here.You can load it to sites like dropbox, onedrive or other reputed site . Please include your sample data , file with code and list structure with sample data. I shall look into it tomorrow.